# Concatonating Strings with PHP & HTML in Wordpress Woocommerce Function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, string-concatenation

I'm trying to add some markup to a string before assigning it to a variable in PHP.

Wordpress/Woocomerce uses a system of "Hooks" to alter the default behaviour. In this case I'm trying to assign a new label to a text field. I currently have:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'My New Label';
     return $fields;
}
?>
```

Which works fine to set the text to `My New Label`, however what I actually want to do is style part of the label using HTML/CSS ( for example have it read "My New *Label*") so I need to escape the PHP, but nothing seems to be working.

I have tried:

`$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'My New' ?> <em> <?php .='Label'?></em><?php;`

I have also tried:

`$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = echo "My New <em>Label</em>";`

And:

`$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = echo 'My New <em>Label</em>';`

Out of desperation I have even tried:

`$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'My New ?> <em> <?php Label ?></em><?php';`

What am I missing?? There must be a way to do this!

Comment: 3 things come to mind that you can check: 1) turn caching off if on, such as WP Super Cache or Total Cache 2) The css styling could be overriding the look of the text. Check the source code with view source or the develeoper console. 3) It could be edited in the wrong place, and that may be a label for a different page, as Woo Commerce has many situations to deal with. But it looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you hopping out of PHP mode? There's no reason for such a badly unreadable statement. Why not just

```
$foo = 'My new <em>Label</em>';
```

?

As well, you need to RTM about [echo](http://php.net/echo). It's not a function. It has no return value. You cannot ever use it the way you're trying.

Comment: Now I feel foolish. Of course that works fine. I was assuming the output would  actually be:

`My new <em>Label</em>`

Because I thought you had to escape php to have any kind of html. I need to RTFM on everything PHP related because it's completely new to me and I'm a terrible programmer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you're describing. It doesn't look like you're concatenating any PHP

```
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'My New<em>Label</em>';
```